# Weak reference to NSManagedObject doesn't get nil

Tags: ios, core-data, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I'm observing strange behaviour of weak references to NSManagedObject. I have a container that has a weak reference to NSManagedObject:

```
class Container: NSObject {
    weak var mo: NSManagedObject?
}
```

assuming that `mo` is some NSManagedObject I have a failed assertion in following code:

```
let container = Container()
container.mo = mo
mo = nil
assert(container.mo == nil) // failed
```

The same test case succeeds if I use NSObject instead of NSManagedObject (both  `container.mo` and `mo`). The context of `mo` doesn't retain its objects (by default).

Whats going on here, why the weak reference doesn't get nilled automatically?
Is this behaviour documented?

Comment: What is the status of `mo` in regard to Core Data? Is it newly inserted? Does it have unsaved changes? Describe the life cycle of `mo` up to this point.

Comment: @TomHarrington in this particular test the mo was fetched from persistent store and doesn't have any changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed objects are cached by CoreData. CoreData is a database. It tres to be efficient. CoreData holds references to the objects it created, and throws them away when it likes. Not when you like it. That's so it doesn't have to re-create the object when it's needed again.

Weak references are guaranteed to be nilled when the object goes away. There is no guarantee when a managed object maintained by CoreData goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `mo = nil` to `container.mo = nil`. Otherwise the reference will still be valid because either:

1. something else has a reference to `mo`
2. `mo` is not deallocated until the end of the current run loop, when the autorelease pool drains. That's when `container.mo` would be `nil` if there are no other references.

Comment: weak reference must be nilled automatically.

Comment: See my updated explanation. ARC does not nil the references immediately.

Comment: regarding run loop, I've just tried to check `container.mo` after some time with `dispatch_after` block. Still doesn't get nil.

Comment: What I've noticed is that `mo.deinit()` doesn't get called. I don't see any retainer for `mo`.

Comment: Something in the core data stack may be privately retaining it.